# Need help with copy constructor for very basic implementation of singly linked lists

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, copy-constructor

Last week, we created a program that manages sets of strings, using classes and vectors. I was able to complete this 100%. This week, we have to replace the vector we used to store strings in our class with simple singly linked lists.

The function basically allows users to declare sets of strings that are empty, and sets with only one element. In the main file, there is a vector whose elements are a struct that contain setName and strSet (class).

HERE IS MY PROBLEM: It deals with the copy constructor of the class. When I remove/comment out the copy constructor, I can declare as many empty or single sets as I want, and output their values without a problem. But I know I will obviously need the copy constructor for when I implement the rest of the program. When I leave the copy constructor in, I can declare one set, either single or empty, and output its value. But if I declare a 2nd set, and i try to output either of the first two sets, i get a Segmentation Fault. Moreover, if i try to declare more then 2 sets, I get a Segmentation Fault. Any help would be appreciated!!

Here is my code for a very basic implementation of everything:

**Here is the setcalc.cpp: (main file)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include "strset2.h"

using namespace std;

// Declares of structure to hold all the sets defined
struct setsOfStr {
    string nameOfSet;
    strSet stringSet;
};

// Checks if the set name inputted is unique
bool isSetNameUnique( vector<setsOfStr> strSetArr, string setName) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < strSetArr.size(); i++) {
        if( strSetArr[i].nameOfSet == setName ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char commandChoice;
    // Declares a vector with our declared structure as the type
    vector<setsOfStr> strSetVec;

    string setName;
    string singleEle;
    // Sets a loop that will constantly ask for a command until 'q' is typed
    while (1) {
            cin >> commandChoice;
        // declaring a set to be empty
        if(commandChoice == 'd') {
            cin >> setName;
            // Check that the set name inputted is unique
            if (isSetNameUnique(strSetVec, setName)  == true) {
                strSet emptyStrSet;
                setsOfStr set1;
                set1.nameOfSet = setName;
                set1.stringSet = emptyStrSet;
                strSetVec.push_back(set1);
            }
            else {
                cerr << "ERROR: Re-declaration of set '" << setName << "'\n";
            }
        }
        // declaring a set to be a singleton
        else if(commandChoice == 's') {
            cin >> setName;
            cin >> singleEle;
            // Check that the set name inputted is unique
            if (isSetNameUnique(strSetVec, setName) == true) {
                strSet singleStrSet(singleEle);
                setsOfStr set2;
                set2.nameOfSet = setName;
                set2.stringSet = singleStrSet;
                strSetVec.push_back(set2);
            }
            else {
                cerr << "ERROR: Re-declaration of set '" << setName << "'\n";
            }
        }
        // using the output function
        else if(commandChoice == 'o') {
            cin >> setName;
            if(isSetNameUnique(strSetVec, setName) == false) {
                // loop through until the set name is matched and call output on its strSet
                for(unsigned int k = 0; k < strSetVec.size(); k++) {
                    if( strSetVec[k].nameOfSet == setName ) {
                            (strSetVec[k].stringSet).output();
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                cerr << "ERROR: No such set '" << setName << "'\n";
            }
        }
        // quitting
        else if(commandChoice == 'q') {
            break;
        }
        else {
            cerr << "ERROR: Ignoring bad command: '" << commandChoice << "'\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Here is the strSet2.h:**

```
#ifndef _STRSET_
#define _STRSET_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct node {
    std::string s1;
    node * next;
};

class strSet {

private:
    node * first;
public:
    strSet ();  // Create empty set
    strSet (std::string s); // Create singleton set
    strSet (const strSet &copy); // Copy constructor
    // will implement destructor and overloaded assignment operator later

    void output() const;


};  // End of strSet class

#endif  // _STRSET_
```

**And here is the strSet2.cpp (implementation of class)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "strset2.h"

using namespace std;

strSet::strSet() {
    first = NULL;
}

strSet::strSet(string s) {
    node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->s1 = s;
    temp->next = NULL;
    first = temp;
}

strSet::strSet(const strSet& copy) {
    cout << "copy-cst\n";
    node *n = copy.first;
    node *prev = NULL;
    while (n) {
        node *newNode = new node;
        newNode->s1 = n->s1;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (prev) {
            prev->next = newNode;
        }
        else {
            first = newNode;
        }
        prev = newNode;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void strSet::output() const {
    if(first == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty set\n";
    }
    else {
        node *temp;
        temp = first;
        while(1) {
            cout << temp->s1 << endl;
            if(temp->next == NULL) break;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this looks a bit peculiar:

```
strSet::strSet(string s) {
    node *temp;
    temp = new node;
    temp->s1 = s;
    temp->next = NULL;
    first = temp;
}
```

what if 'first' is pointing to something already? You are then effectively killing the previous list and causing a mem leak.

Comment: `first` is not pointing to something already before this function is called, because the function is a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ standard states that types used in a standard container (such as std::vector) must be copy constructable AND assignable.

Since you have not implemented a custom assignment operator on the class strSet, the compiler will generate one for you that does a simple memberwise copy. In your case, this means the 'first' pointer will be copied directly. Obviously this means two objects now 'own' the nodes in the set, and you will get a crash when it is freed twice.

Some tips:

1. Implement a custom assignment operator that does the same thing as your copy constructor
2. Read up on passing objects by reference, and by const reference where possible. You are doing a lot of unnecessary copying of your containers and strings when you pass by value.

e.g.

bool isSetNameUnique(const vector& strSetArr, const string& setName)

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `strSet` copy constructor does not assign the member `first` when its argument is empty.  This causes Undefined Behavior.

Also, the `strSet` assignment operator (`operator=`) that was shown before the edit was definitely wrong; and it really is not a good idea to define a copy constructor but allow the destructor and assignment operator to be implicitly defined by the compiler.  See the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

One common way to implement the Big Three when they need to do considerable management (like in this case) looks something like:

```
class strSet {
private:
    void cleanup();
    void create_from(const node* n);
// ...
};

strSet::~strSet() { cleanup(); }

strSet::strSet(const strSet& copy) : first(NULL) { create_from(copy.first); }

strSet& strSet::operator=(const strSet& rtSide) {
    if (this != &rtSide) {
        cleanup(); // trash old contents of *this
        create_from(rtSide.first); // clone contents of rtSide
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: When declaring lets say empty sets (so if input command was just 'd'), I don't use the overloaded '=' operator correct? I'm just not sure why I keep getting Segmentation Fault when I declare 3 empty sets in a row. If I declare one, it works fine and I can output its value. If i declare two sets, as soon as I try to output value I get "Segmentation Fault" and if i try to declare 3 sets, as soon as I try I get "Segmentation Fault". This shouldn't have to access the overloaded '=' operator.

Comment: @Jesus: Found your other problem and edited my answer.  But if you don't declare an `operator=` yourself, the compiler will make one up for you, and what it comes up with is not necessarily safe.

Comment: Okay, perfect! Thanks for the help, appreciate it!